# Corona SDK Build Android not responding

Tags: android, build, sdk, coronasdk

I am having a problem with corona sdk , I tried to make a simple game and its fine but when I go to the emulator I go to File -> Build for Android -> I write the details of the app then build it opens a window to make the app, its called Build Progress, loads then stops in the middle and says Not Responding , I tried many apps and still didn't work , what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Click Build and don't touch anything... wait for 5 mins. It goes through internet and it is not well developed. Keep window active and wait.